# Create a reactive function outside the shiny app

Tags: r, module, shiny

I am trying to decompose the code of my shiny app in order to improve readability and to test some functions using the `testthat` package.

I would like to have some files (for example `server_utils.R`) in which I can write "normal" functions that I can test and then make them reactive.

For example I would like to have something like this in `server_utils.R`:

```
my_sum <- function(x, y) {
  x + y
}
```

and something like this in the app:

```
my_sum_reactive(input$x, input$y)
```

Do you know if a such behavior is possible?

Comment: Have a look at modules: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shiny modules is what might help you.

See here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

As you can read in the article the desired functionality to pass in input is possible if you wrap the input in a `reactive()` function. (See the end of the "Writing server functions" section of the article).

You would define the `my_sum` function as follows:
(Note that you have to use the variables `a` and `b` as reactives `a()` and `b()` and wrap the result in a `reactive()` function.)

```
my_sum <- function(input, output, session, a, b) {
  reactive(as.numeric(a()) + as.numeric(b()))
}
```

And could use it as:

```
my_sum_reactive <- callModule(my_sum, "id", reactive(input$a), reactive(input$b))
```

which is then usable as:

`my_sum_reactive()`

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)

my_sum <- function(input, output, session, a, b) {
  reactive(as.numeric(a()) + as.numeric(b()))
}

ui <- fluidPage({
  fluidRow(
    selectInput("a", "a", 1:3),
    selectInput("b", "b", 1:3),
    textOutput("txt")
  )
})

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_sum_reactive <- callModule(my_sum, "id", reactive(input$a), reactive(input$b))
  output$txt <- renderText(paste0("The sum is: ", my_sum_reactive())) 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is really interesting. I was thinking that I could also have just done something like: `reactive(my_sum(input$x, input$y)` in the server. This should still work but for sure is not elegant.

Comment: I going to figure out if it solves my problem. if it does the trick I will accept the answer.