# Workflow for maintaining different versions of a Shiny app

Tags: r, git, shiny

Lately I have been making several very similar Shiny apps for different clients and hosting them on shinyapps.io.

Each app has a different title, different data, some differences in branding etc. but otherwise the code is very similar.

I'm having trouble maintaining these apps. When find and fix a bug I currently have to go through 5 different apps and make the change each time.

Does anyone have good suggestions on how to handle this? Git branches? I know the best solution would be to have one app and upload different data, but that's not possible unfortunately.

I'd like to keep using shinyapps.io, but I'm open to hosting the apps somewhere else if it makes my workflow better.

Comment: if they share the same routines you could look into bundling those routines into a package and maintain the shared routines from there

Comment: Sounds like shiny modules might help here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html. As you seem to use code several times you could define the reactive functions outside shiny, update them there and call them in the relevant apps with `callModule()`. I wrote a minimum example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976128/create-a-reactive-function-outside-the-shiny-app/43976516#43976516.

Comment: Git branching might help.  You could have a central branch with common functionality and then branches for each app.  Common bug fixes would happen in `master` and the other branches could sync to that.

Comment: @AdamSpannbauer that's a really good idea that I can't believe I didn't think of...

Comment: @BigDataScientist I'm reading your link just now and it looks really interesting. Not something I knew about before.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this was my first idea but I've read a few other answers about maintaining different versions of code and they generally seemed against it. Part of me thinks it might be fine because my project is pretty simple though.

Comment: Branches are usually setup to ultimately be merged back into their source.  If this isn't the case, you could also consider creating a common library which all your Shiny apps would share.  Then if a bug be discovered in the core base you'd only need to fix it in one place.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the comment `shinyModules()` will help you: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

Shiny modules are to shiny functions, like ordinary functions are to repeating code.

Or to put it differently:

- Repeating code --> function
- repeating shiny function --> shiny module

As the documentation is a bit complicated here and there, i wrote a simplified example here:
[Create a reactive function outside the shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976128/create-a-reactive-function-outside-the-shiny-app/43976516#43976516).

You could store all the shiny modules in a file `modules.R` and add a `global.R` script to each of the apps that loads the modules (`source("../modules.R"`). Then you only have to update the functions within `modules.R`. That change of structure might take a while in the beginning. But, i think in the long run it pays off for more complex apps.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a library that contained most of the code I needed for the apps, as suggested by Adam Spannbauer in the comments.

It's not perfect; I still have some duplication and I have to have the library on GitHub so that it will work with shinyapps.io. However, it's a big improvement on what I was doing previously.