# Avoiding code duplication in Shiny Reactive Expressions

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm new to Shiny so forgive me if this question is misguided.

Say I have 2 separate inputs `input$n_1` and `input$n_2` that invoke nearly identical code.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    numericInput("n_1", label = "n1", value = 5000),
    numericInput("n_2", label = "n2", value = 5000),
    textOutput("result1"),
    textOutput("result2")
  )
)

server <- function(input,output,session)({

  generate_result1 <- reactive({
    # A whole lot of code to generate a result using input$n_1
    x = input$n_1 * 5
  })

  generate_result2 <- reactive({
    # A whole lot of identical code to generate a result using but using input$n_2.  
    # This example only shows one line of code but the real code has dozens of  
    # lines of code where the only difference from generate_result1 is that it uses 
    # input$n_2 instead of input$n_1.
    x = input$n_2 * 5
  })

  output$result1 <- renderText(generate_result1())
  output$result2 <- renderText(generate_result2())

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there a way to avoid the code duplication currently found in `generate_result1` and `generate_result2` in the example above?

Comment: Any progress in fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand the process of obtaining `generate_result1`, and  `generate_result2`, are very similar. The only difference is **they receive different inputs**.

In this case, you should write a function and pass the inputs to it

```
generate_result<- function(input){
  # bla bla bla
   reactive( final_result)  
}
```

and then call it based on different inputs, as below:

```
server <- function(input,output,session)({


  output$result1 <- renderText({generate_result(input$n_1)})
  output$result2 <- renderText({generate_result(input$n_2)})

})
```

Comment: `input$n_1 * 5` is an overly simplistic example.  There's dozens of lines of code that are all the same except with the `input` being used.

Comment: I'll give this a try and see if I have more questions

Comment: of course ... just trying to figure out if this solve my issue

Comment: I still can't figure this out ... the example you give works but it complains about not being in a reactive environment in my code.  For what it's worth, my output is a `rhandsontable`

Comment: your final return value of function should be reactive, please find this question, and i will update my answer as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976128/create-a-reactive-function-outside-the-shiny-app

Comment: this works ... I was having an issue because I was using the render function for `rhandsontable` incorrectly.