# shiny reactivePoll re-use for multiple database table names

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dashboard that relies on 25+ database tables. I want to refresh this data periodically. Shiny `reactivePoll` that checks row count on each table, and then reads the table when row count increases is the correct thing for my case.

But, I don't want to write 25+ `reactivePoll` methods, one for each table. Instead, I want to define a 'generic' one and re-use it by simply supplying the database table name.

I can't find a way to do it. Any ideas? Conceptually, here is what I would like:

```
pollData <- reactivePoll(60000, session,
  checkFunc = function() {
    dbconn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), group = 'mysql')
    query <- dbSendQuery(dbconn,
                         '
                         SELECT
                             MAX(timeCreated) as lastCreated
                         FROM
                             <table name passed as argument>;
                         ')
    lastFeedback <- dbFetch(query, -1)
    dbClearResult(query)
    dbDisconnect(dbconn)

    lastFeedback$lastCreated
  },

  # This function returns the content of the logfile
  valueFunc = function() {
    dbconn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), group = 'mysql')
    query <- dbSendQuery(dbconn,
                         '
                         SELECT
                             *
                         FROM
                         <table name passed as argument>
                         ')
    data <- dbFetch(query, -1)
    dbClearResult(query)
    dbDisconnect(dbconn)

    data
  }
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    table1Data <- pollData(<table1 name>)
    table2Data <- pollData(<table2 name>)
    ....
    ....
}
```

NOTE: I understand that I can move the `checkFunc` and `valueFunc` out and make them generic, however, it will still require 25+ reactivePoll() definitions that invoke these other two functions. That is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a more general answer at this question: [Create a reactive function outside the shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976128/create-a-reactive-function-outside-the-shiny-app)

It cites: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html I believe you are trying to build a shiny module. In your case it could look something like follows (a function which calls a reactive function):

```
my.reactivePoll <- function(session, table_name, timeout = 60000)
{
  my.dataframe <- reactivePoll(timeout, session,
                   checkFunc = function() {
                           lastFeedback <- "testValue"
                           # checking logic here
                           lastFeedback
                         },

                         # This function returns the content of the logfile
                         valueFunc = function() {
                           data <- paste0("New value", table_name)
                           # value logic here
                           data
                         })
  my.dataframe
}
```

Then make calls in the server function, supplying the `table_name`

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  table1Data <- my.reactivePoll(session, "table1")
  table2Data <- my.reactivePoll(session, "table2")
}
```

Comment: is this going to be an efficient solution though? maybe  i'm understanding incorrectly, but won't `reactivePoll` be running `n` different `checkFunc`'s?

rather than building one `checkFunc` that checks if any tables have changed, and then updating the appropriate table?

Comment: Hmm, sorry but I wrote this answer a year ago. I believe it works for the question that was asked. Anyway if my understanding is correct then you need a reactive for each thing you are monitoring.